# Measure Courier character width to fill a Listbox

Tags: c#, string, graphics, fonts

I am trying to write a method that given a description and a tag will return a padded string that fills a line in my list box. I thought I might have had it with my current code, but I noticed that it overestimated the width of the characters with `Graphics.MeasureString(...)`. After some digging I found that `MeasureString` returns its value in units of `PageUnits` which an enumeration [GraphicsUnits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphicsunit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Below is an SSCCE I have created to show my problem. I am not sure how I can convert from the given `PageUnit` to pixels. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StringPadProj
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            theListBox.Items.Add(getPaddedStr("meow", "[Cat]"));
            theListBox.Items.Add(getPaddedStr("woof", "[Dog]"));
            theListBox.Items.Add(getPaddedStr("chirp", "[Bird]"));
            theListBox.Items.Add(getPaddedStr("cricket", "[Cricket]"));
        }

        private String getPaddedStr(String desc, String tag)
        {
            int availSpacePx = theListBox.Width;
            Console.Out.WriteLine("ListBoxW: " + availSpacePx);
            Graphics e = theListBox.CreateGraphics();
            e.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
            Font listBFont = theListBox.Font;
            SizeF charSize = e.MeasureString("k", listBFont);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("CharSize: " + charSize);
            int numCharPerLine = (int)Math.Floor(availSpacePx / charSize.Width);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("CharsPerLine: " + numCharPerLine);

            int tagLen = tag.Length;
            int spaceLeft = numCharPerLine - tagLen;
            if (desc.Length > spaceLeft)
                desc = desc.Substring(0, spaceLeft);
            else if (desc.Length < spaceLeft)
                while (desc.Length < spaceLeft)
                    desc += " ";
            String itemText = desc + tag;

            return itemText;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.theListBox = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // theListBox
            // 
            this.theListBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.theListBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.theListBox.ItemHeight = 14;
            this.theListBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.theListBox.Name = "theListBox";
            this.theListBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(350, 172);
            this.theListBox.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(374, 198);
            this.Controls.Add(this.theListBox);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox theListBox;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

So it seems that `MeasureString(...)` is doing exactly what it should be. From what I can tell the issue has to lie with the units of the `theListBox.Width` value. It seems that they are not measured in pixels. I actually cannot find anything that references what exactly the units are for [`Control.Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.width%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So the question is now, how to convert/find the units of `Control.Width` to pixels?

Comment: You'll get GraphicsUnit.Display.  Which uses pixels as a unit in most practical cases.  There's a subtle difference if your program is not running dpiAware and the display is operating at a DPI setting of 144 or larger.  None that matters to your program.  Your problem doesn't have anything to do with that, everything to do with typography rules.  You'll get a "larger" value to account for glyph overhang.  Pixel-perfect text measurement isn't really possible.

Comment: So basically, give up and hard code a few measured values? // Prior to this I would just insert the string "0123456789" repeating into the text box and just count the number of characters it would fit. I wanted to make it so I could resize the ListBox. so I guess I might might a few measurements and just hardcode a character width value for the font I use.

Comment: You must use TextRenderer.MeasureText instead, that's what ListBox uses.  And set the ClientSize.Width, not Width.

Comment: `TextRenderer.MeasureText` returns a size that is 3-4 units larger in the width, but 0.2 units smaller on the height. It makes the measurement even further off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: New answer:

MSDN on [MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6xe5hazb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says it all:

> The MeasureString method is designed for use with individual strings
>   and includes a small amount of extra space before and after the string
>   to allow for overhanging glyphs. Also, the DrawString method adjusts
>   glyph points to optimize display quality and might display a string
>   narrower than reported by MeasureString. To obtain metrics suitable
>   for adjacent strings in layout (for example, when implementing
>   formatted text), use the MeasureCharacterRanges method or one of the
>   MeasureString methods that takes a StringFormat, and pass
>   GenericTypographic. Also, ensure the TextRenderingHint for the
>   Graphics is AntiAlias.

So, changing the measure command to something like this will get you the measure of a single character suitable to be multiplied (when using a monospace font, as you do):

```
SizeF charSize = e.MeasureString("k", listBFont, 
                                 PointF.Empty, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
```

Comment: Hmm, good idea. This produces the same result though. // Assuming that `MeasureString(...)` is not broken. Maybe `ListBox.Width` does not return a pixel value. That's the only other thing that makes sense.

Comment: ListBox.Width is in Pixels, but maybe using ListBox.ClientRectangle.Width would be better?

Comment: Can you link me to something that says that it is in pixels? // ClientRectangle is 4 *units* smaller than the width.

Comment: All Controls dimensions are in pixels; we are talking Winforms, right? The Clientsize is without the borders, hence the difference

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last comment, leave what out? // I never set the "Fonts" GraphicUnit to point..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55769/discussion-between-taw-and-anotheruser).

Comment: // Ok the edited answer works a lot better. Though not exactly perfect because it removes the padding between letters, it is close enough to be useful. Thanks a lot for the effort @TaW